# Wrong format when passing an array of strings to java script from Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a rather atypical set-up in one of my Rails controllers in that it can create a series of objects (instead of only a single one) depending the parameters received.

I'd like the controller to respond_to js and pass such group of objects, just created, as an array to my js.erb file.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to pass the array to JS in the appropriate format.

A bit of pseudo code to illustrate my controller below:

**Controllers/verbatims_controller.rb**

```
 def create
  # Code here returns an array of strings 
  # Each string of the array is converted into a Verbatim instance
  # I create again an array of strings by 'plucking' the 'content' attribute (a string) from each verbatim object 
  # I set @verbatims to take the value of that array of strings as below
  @verbatims = @answer.verbatims.pluck(:content)
  # At this point I'm sure @verbatims returns an array of the form ["string_1", "string_2", "string_n"] 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'verbatims_for_answers.js.erb'
  end
end
```

**Views/verbatims/verbatims_for_answers.js.erb**

```
// I set my JS variable as below
var verbatims = ("<%= j @verbatims.to_json %>");
// which returns a string like:
"[&quot;string_1&quot;,&quot;string_2&quot;,&quot;string_n&quot;]"
```

I have tried using raw as suggested in a post in StackOverflow without success like:

```
var verbatims = ("<%= raw @verbatims.to_json %>");
```

Or converting to json from the controller but still no luck.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Try `"<%= @verbatims.to_json.html_safe %>"`

Comment: thanks Pravan just tried it and I got an JS error. I tried:
`"<%= j @verbatims.to_json.html_safe %>"` and it works to get rid of the &quot; but it still results in a string like this:
`"["s_1", "s_2", s_n"]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra quotation marks:

```
var verbatims = <%= raw @verbatims.to_json %>;
```

Comment: Thanks vijoc. I didn't notice the code with the `raw` command was meant to be without the quotes.